# Smallest distance between point and hyperbola

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate the minimum distance between the hyperbola $x^2-2y^2=1$ and the point $(0, 1)$.

Frankly, I am not sure how to attack this problem. I can think of trying to straight forward express the distance as

$$
d = \sqrt{x^2 + (y-1)^2}
$$
and try to minimize it under the constraint  $x^2-2y^2=1$, but that doesn't seem to make it any easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost finished. There is only routine calculation left to do.

Note that $x^2=2y^2+1$, so you can express the distance nicely as a function of $y$. And we might as well minimize the square of the distance.